# like or comment notification in pidgin

Tags: 13.04, pidgin, facebook

I am new in ubuntu and I am using Ubuntu 13 and pidgin. I am using facebook login in pidgin. I want to get the like or comment notification also through pidgin.

Can I get like or comment notification through pidgin?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Pidgin doesn't support notification for a post, that gets a Like or Comment.

Pidgin supports Facebook chat through XMPP protocol. By using Facebook chat via pidgin you can send a text chat and emoticons.

For other information. Please refer [Pidgin FAQ](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/FAQ)

Alternate way to get notifications is by installing FBMessenger, a stand-alone facebook messenger for Linux.

To install **FBMessenger**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fbmessenger
```

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/fbmessenger-stand-alone-facebook.html)

Comment: then which is the messenger by which I can also get notification of likes or comments?